# Visual Effects Graph - My tornado becomes a sinusoidal wall instead of rotating in a conical, tornado-like shape

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles, particle-system, visual-effects

**OBJECTIVE**

I am making my first Visual Effects Graph effect. I want to create a tornado.

**WHERE I AM**

I managed to get the particles to spin in a tubular shape:

[image]

Here is my graph:

[image]

**PROBLEM**

I can't get them to spin in a conical shape.

**WHAT I TRIED**

I tried hooking up the following nodes to the "X" variable of "Rotate 3D" node's "Rotation Center":

"total time", "VFX time (delta time)", "Get attribute: age", "Age over lifetime".

The one that came closest was VFX time which became ever so slightly conical, though I might be imagining it.

I expected "Get attribute: age" to work but instead I got this weird sinusoidal wall shape

[image]

How can I achieve a conical, tornado-like shape? I would also appreciate any other tips or resources to achieve this particular effect.

Answer (score 0):

Someone on Reddit helped me make it go up in a conical shape but now, of course but still rather unfortunately, I have a different problem. The tornado only goes up in a conical fashion when set velocity is turned off. When it's not, it forms a spiral-shaped wall.

Anyway, here is the solution:

[image]